# Jsctags are not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim, ctags, jsctags

I installed `jsctags`, but when I use it according to its [usage](https://github.com/evilpie/jsctags) section it ends with [this](http://pastebin.com/MJjnHUJL) error.

It is required to have `node.js` installed and added it's location to `$PATH`.
I installed `node.js` as an Ubuntu package with `apt-get` and the file `nodejs` is located in `/usr/bin` which is in my `$PATH` variable.

Do you know what is wrong and how to make `jsctags` work?

thank you

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like a narcissus (an external tool used by jsctags) error but could you put somewhere the piece(s) of JavaScript on which you get this error? And indicate the version number of jsctags?

Comment: I tried on less complex project. `jsctags .` was OK, but when I run `:TagBarOpen` in vim it writes [this](http://pastebin.com/CFmt4ETk)

Comment: So running `jsctags .` in `/home/xralf/firefox/popup_alt/components/` creates a `/home/xralf/firefox/popup_alt/components/tags` file with the expected content but Tagbar somehow can't use `jsctags`? Does running the exact same command as Tagbar (`jsctags -f - loader.js`) works? Both `jsctags` and Tagbar are very efficient here, even on "large" projects with a dozen 1000+ lines JavaScript files; using it on small projects won't work better in any noticeable way. Could you post `loader.js`? Did you consider posting an issue on either tool's github page? Can you call `jsctags` from within Vim?

Comment: It seems my `jsctags` has no `-f` option. The `loader.js` is part of [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/popup-alt-attribute/?src=search) addon. The tags file was created with some content.

Comment: OK, I need more room so I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of `jsctags` I have here and at work (at home: built on 2011.05.10, at work: I don't know but probably the same day +- 2 or 3 days) accepts either `-f -` or `-o -` as options to write to `stdout` which is the mechanism used by TagBar.

I've just built the latest version pulled from github and it doesn't seem to accept `-f` anymore. `-o -` sort of works but it actually writes a `-` tags file right next to the `jsctags` executable.

So basically the whole thing is busted as of right now.

I suggest you contact the authors to find a solution/workaround.

In the mean time, you could checkout an old revision of `jsctags` and see if it helps.

Comment: @romaini Could you please post a SHA-1 of your revision?

Comment: OK. What a colossal waste of time: our `jsctags` are different. Yours comes from [here](https://github.com/evilpie/jsctags) (it is the first version and is pretty much abandonned since more than 1 year), mine comes from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs) (it is the current version). Try with the DoctorJS version. I think it's my fault for giving you a bad link in the first place. Please accept my apologies. I wanted to be snarky and tell you to search for yourself on github. Instead I did the search and gave you wrong informations. Next time, I WILL BE SNARKY.

Comment: @romainl I appreciate your help. Actually I did the search too and found doctorJS but wasn't sure if it's the right thing (the same you advised me). Now there is another problem with [build](http://pastebin.com/v0npMZpE) which is undescribed on their pages. Do you had this error too? I believe that this can be useful to other coders too.

Comment: This one is easy but poorly documented: you need to build narcissus before jsctags. When it's done, the correct files will be found.

Comment: I downloaded narcissus to the correct directory and installed doctorjs but when I use the command `jsctags .` another [error](http://pastebin.com/bNgAyzAm) occurs.

Comment: Aaaarrrgh. By the look of the stack trace you now have a problem with node itself but I have zero experience with it. It looks like some module is missing. It's entirely possible that `jsctags` depends on a library that is not available anymore in core node or any other reasons. You'll be better served by creating an "issue" on doctorjs' github page. BTW, stay away from any casino, your bad luck is unbelievable ;-).

Comment: I just installed the whole thing (node + jsctags/narcissus) from the latest sources on an Ubuntu VPS (didn't want to mess with my working setup at home) and I've got a different error running jsctags against itself.

Answer (score 0):

jsctags filename > tags. Use -f for ctags format.